# ideal way to restart nested loops in C?

Tags: c, while-loop, nested

I am a newbie to microcontroller C programming and I am running into a few problems with using nested loops.
Following is a sample construct that I have in my C code. The problems are mentioned subsequently

```
// I am trying to ramp down the while loop
while (i>= stop_value)
{
    step_value = default_value;
    R32(a particular register, content_register);
    if (content_register = a_set_value)
    {
        if( step_value <= step_max)
        {
            step_value = step_value +1;
            i=start_value;
            continue;
        }
        if(step_value =step_max)
        {
            // do something;
            break;
        }
    }
    WR32(a particular register, content_reset_register); // resetting the register
    i=i-1;
}
```

Basically, I am trying to do the following:
ramp down a loop till it reaches the stop_value and also read a particular register while ramping down.
If the register has a defined value, then check if the step_value<= step_max. If step_value < step_max then reset the while loop by using continue statement, and setting i to initial start value. At this point of time, my step_value should be the latest value and not the default step value. I do understand that above code is not completely correct for step_value because I initialize step_value to default_value.( So, how do I modify the initial step_value = default_value statement so that first time when the loop executes, I have a default_value and subsequently the most recent step_value?)
But, if step_value equals my step_max then just do something and break subsequently( this part works!). Also, when I use the  continue statement, I should reset the contents of the register.

So, I want to effectively reset the while loop with the latest step_value, contents of the register reset when my step_value is less than step_max? Thank you for your replies!

Comment: @simonc well done for persevering with that edit. :)

Comment: Make sure your R32 read register is declared 'volatile' so that the compiler doesn't optimize away the read.  Also =/== as below.

Comment: _how do I modify the initial step_value = default_value statement so that first time when the loop executes, I have a default_value and subsequently the most recent step_value_? Simply move `step_value = default_value` above the loop, so that when you reset `i` and `continue` it wouldn't be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
   if( step_value <= step_max)
    {
        step_value = step_value +1;
        i=start_value;
        continue;
    }
    if(step_value =step_max)
    {
        // do something;
        break;
    }
```

The second if cannot ever be reached.  You are checking <= and then skipping to the bottom of the loop with continue.

From your above logic:

> then check if the step_value<= step_max. If step_value < step_max then reset the while loop by using continue statement, and setting i to initial start value.

That code should probably read:

```
   if( step_value < step_max)
    {
        step_value = step_value +1;
        i=start_value;
        continue;
    }
    ...
```

Then the second if could be evaluated.  This should be generating compiler warnings like crazy about unreachable code and assignment within if statements.  Please turn on your compiler warnings and listen to them!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that at least one of the following alternatives apply:

**First**, in **C** language `=` is an assigment which returns the value assigned and assumes true if that value is not equal to `0`.
So you have to use `==`  in all if statements instead of `=` (unless it is desired behaviour that you assign and check for != 0 in the if statement in one step - but even in that case I'd prefer to do this in 2 steps for better maintainability), i.e. instead of

```
if (content_register = a_set_value)
    {
            // your code
    }
```

I would say

```
content_register = a_set_value;
if (content_register!=0)
    {
            // your code
    }
```

to make it more clear what you're checking against.

**Second**, if `step_value==step_max` (and you're properly using `==` in the 2nd `if`) then both IFs are executed, which is not what you want. So you I assume you meant `<` instead of `<=`.

**Third**, from our chat I got the information from you that the loop is waiting for a register change coming from an external thread. In this case the loop is simply too fast resetting the register. Consider synchronization or at least add a thread sleep after resetting the register to allow the other thread to change the register.

Change this and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I have modified the if statements so as to execute only one if statement depending on the condition and now, what I see is the while loop runs continuously till it reaches stop value. But this is not what we want. I am guessing the problem behind this is because the contents of register are being reset for every loop and thereby, while loop runs till the stop_value.

Comment: I think to better understand this, you need to describe what the functions R32 and WR32 are doing - I assume R32 is for read, WR32 for write? Are you waiting for an external task to set this register? If that is the case and you reset the same register each iteration, there is no time for the external task to update it, because the reset comes too fast. You need to put a sleep command after the reset to allow the other task update the value. But a better approach is to use a semaphore or monitor to synchronize the tasks.

Comment: Yes, R32 is for read function and WR32 is for write and read the contents( to check if correct content has been written). Yes, I am waiting for an external task to set this register. I have actually thought about the probability of my reset being too fast and therefore, I have created a dummy for loop to allow sufficient time.

Comment: Also, all my register are declared volatile. Now, from what I can analyze, the problem has got to do with this particular register that is being reset and set again. As a trial case, if I do not reset it, then I am checking if step_value < step_mac loop and then subsequently incrementing step_value so as to reach step_max. If step_max is reached, I do something and then break the loop. But, if I use this register to reset and set it again, then the program just ramps down till i reaches stop_value.Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: Look for something like a thread sleep function rather than doing a "busy wait" - creating a delay via loop has two disadvantages: 1. The timing is hardware-dependant (if you upgrade your CPU the original timing might fail) and 2. It costs you processor time.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. Yes, the problem indeed was insufficient settling time between the 'content_register' getting reset and again being set to ' a
_set_value'. After I played around so as to allow sufficient settling time, my code performs as expected. Thanks a lot for all your help and valuable suggestions:-)